# Asp.Net MVC Populate RDLC Report to PDF Directly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I've created a report using SQL Server Report Builder 2008. 
I was wondering if there were any examples out there on how to have this run in an Asp.net MVC App. I figured that setting the datasource and streaming it directly to a pdf file would be do-able, but i keep getting the following error when LocalReports Render Method is called.

```
"{"The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded."}"
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a project on codeplex which does this.
If anyones interested it's located here -> http://mvcrdlc.codeplex.com/